# Netbeans won't let me change a project's Netbeans platform

Tags: netbeans, visualvm

I've downloaded the VisualVM source and am trying to compile the Glassfish plugin using Netbeans 7.01. Doing so results in the following error:

C:\source\visualvm\trunk\plugins\glassfish\nbproject\build-impl.xml:48: You must define 'nbplatform.VisualVM_100609-dd12ae64a19c.harness.dir'

That lead me to the project settings which shows the platform as "Netbeans IDE...". The drop down box is grayed out so I can't select the correct platform.
[image]

Yet, on my hello world VisualVM plugin I can set the platform to the appropriate platform and it runs great.
[image]

To try and resolve this I've tried creating platform.properties file and putting it in the nbproject folder with the following entries. However, this doesn't seem to be working

> harness.dir=mypath/visualvm/visualvm_13
>
> and
>
> nbplatform.VisualVM_100609-dd12ae64a19c.harness.dir=mypath/visualvm/visualvm_13

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to build the VisualVM and it's associated plugins you must download the NetBeans platform and profiler binaries that are available on the VisualVM website's [build guide section](http://visualvm.java.net/build.html).

For example, to build the 1.3.2 release you would go to [this section](http://visualvm.java.net/build/build132.html) and download the NetBeans 6.9.1 platform and profiler binaries available through the link located on that page.  The link I've provided also gives you instructions for obtaining the proper VisualVM sources from the repository and building VisualVM and it's plugins.  For example, the sources for the 1.3.2 release can be checked out using the following url:

```
https://svn.java.net/svn/visualvm~svn/branches/release132
```

And once you've completed the checkout and extracted the NetBeans platform binaries (downloaded from the above link) into the 
`release132/visualvm` directory, you can build the entire application and it's plugins by running `ant build` from the `release32/plugins` directory.

I successfully completed this entire process and can verify that the instructions work for **1.3.2**.  However, the instructions for building the trunk did not result in a successful build due to at least one missing dependency.

What the error that you were seeing was telling you was that the NetBeans platform's build harness could not be located.  The harness is included in the downloadable binary and once you've extracted it into the `release32/visualvm` directory the values that are in the `project.properties` file will once again be valid.  This is of course a good example of why you should keep everything needed to successfully reproduce a build in your repository!

Comment: The link to the release page got me going in the correct direction. I was missing the binaries. Thanks!

Comment: Can we have the same link again? it's look like unavailable. Can anyone help me out to find binary file for visualvm ?

Answer (score 1):

Glassfish plugin is part of 'plugins' NetBeans modules suite. All modules from a Modules suite has to be build against the same version of NetBeans platform application (in our case VisualVM). This means that you can change the NetBeans Platform for the whole suite, go to the properties of the 'plugins' suite a change the platform there.

Comment: Yeah that's a lot better than my answer!

Comment: I'm still looking at both answers. Thanks guys. It's a side project so I'll get the answer marked accordingly at some point.